# connecting datatable with datagrid asp.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

so i was trying to bind my datagrid to a datatable and i came up with this code
now everything seems to be working but it does not shows nothing on my gridview it doesnt even shows the datagrid at all when i execute anyone know what is the problem because i cant figure it out everything should be working fine but the gridview does not load .

```
  Dim mrDB As New Odbc.OdbcConnection(myDAC.OBDC)
    Dim dgrMR As New DataTable
    Dim dr As DataRow

    dgrMR.Columns.Add("Data")
    dgrMR.Columns.Add("Utente")
    dgrMR.Columns.Add("Nome")
    dgrMR.Columns.Add("Série")
    dgrMR.Columns.Add("Tipo")
    dgrMR.Columns.Add("Estado")

    dgvMarcacoes.Columns.Clear()


    Dim sqlStr As String = "select distinct data,idno,idnome, u_tratam as serie, u_tipomr, Max(estado) as estado " &
                            "from [marca].[mr]"

    sqlStr += queryFilter
    sqlStr += "group by idno,idnome, u_tratam, data, u_tipomr "
'this msgbox shows a correct string (that works on sql) so the problem is not on this part
    'MsgBox(sqlStr, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "controlo")

    mrDB.Open()
    Dim mrComm As New Odbc.OdbcCommand(sqlStr, mrDB)

    Dim mrReader = mrComm.ExecuteReader
    Dim b = New StringBuilder()
    If Not (mrReader.HasRows) Then
        Me.dgvMarcacoes.Visible = False
        MsgBox("Não há marcações para o dia indicado", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation + MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "ATENÇÃO...")
    Else
        'Me.dgvMarcacoes.Visible = True
        While mrReader.Read
            dr = dgrMR.NewRow()

            dr(0) = Trim(mrReader(0))
            dr(1) = Trim(mrReader(1))
            dr(2) = Trim(mrReader(2))
            dr(3) = Trim(mrReader(3))
            dr(4) = Trim(mrReader(4))
            dr(5) = Trim(mrReader(5))
            dgrMR.Rows.Add(dr)

            'dr.Item(5).Value = Trim(estado(mrReader(5)))

        End While

    End If

    dgvMarcacoes.DataSource = dgrMR
    dgvMarcacoes.DataBind()
    mrDB.Close()
'so i tried this to see if the data was passing correctly to my datatable and it is :\
    For i = 0 To dgrMR.Rows.Count - 1
        For u = 0 To dgrMR.Columns.Count - 1
            MsgBox(dgrMR.Rows(i)(u).ToString)
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: Sorry, but: is punctuation completely out of fashion ? ;-)

Comment: ain't nobody got time for that xD

Comment: Well, if you don't care about taking the time to make your question clear for the readers it's up to you. But don't be surprised if you will not get many answers... (Or maybe it's just that I'm old fashioned, don't know...)

Comment: i was just joking, its not like i did it on purpose, its just that english is not my native language and im not sure where to use punctuation. i'l try to get the hang of it, if it really botters the readers :)

Comment: ok. Sorry if I didn't get the joke. Let's say that even just some full stops at the end of sentences could help ! ;-)

Comment: got it, thanks for the tip mate :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a tag as `asp.net` but you have `MsgBox` in your code indicating that is a WinForm application. Check if the grid columns are `AutogenerateColumns=True` and change it to `false`

Comment: well as you told me to check the AutogenerateColumn i managed to figure out that it was actually the visibility that for some reason was false

Comment: @Halamahala leave it. It might help someone

Comment: @Halamahala Are you *sure* the message box works just fine? Have you really thought it threw? You know how the web works? HTML, CSS, JavaScript? How do you think the message box class from Windows Forms is going to work over HTTP? I'll give you a hint: it won't work as soon as your server and client cease to be the same machine.

Comment: yes but the msgbox wont be shown to the actual user i just putted it there so i could see what was being inserted on the table

Comment: but thanks anyway because i didnt know the msgbox wouldn't work if i actually needed to show it to the user.

Comment: im new to asp.net so any tips are greatly apreciated so thank you :)